# Чтение нескольких файлов по шаблону и создание соответствующих директорий с файлами

Tags: python, python-3.x

Стоит задача поочередного чтения множества CSV-файлов в директории *data*, затем требуется создать директории для считанных файлов в директории *result* (например, *project/result/filter1* и т.д.). После этого в каждой из результирующей директории создать несколько CSV-файлов, в которые будет производиться частичная запись по фильтрам.

На данный момент это реализовано следующим образом:

```py
finName = ["filter1.csv", "filter2.csv", "filter3.csv", "filter4.csv"]
dataDir = getcwd()+"/data/"
resDir = getcwd()+"/result/"
dataRaw = [f for f in listdir(dataDir) if isfile(join(dataDir, f))]
finDir = [d for d in listdir(dataDir) if makedirs(join(resDir, splitext(d)[0]), exist_ok=True)]
```

Проблема заключается в том, что в *finDir* ничего не записывается, и, в связи с этим, не получается создать итоговые файлы по шаблону. Есть ли какие-то альтернативы или я что-то упускаю? Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: Это условия задачи или часть кода?